# Import XML into PostgreSQL database or Convert XML -> CSV -> PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, csv, xml-parsing

I have XML file

```
<Cluster clsId="UNIPR_NIRI_PARDP" semType="geneProt"> <Entry entryId="UNIPR_NIRI_PARDP_1" baseForm="Protein nirI" type="PREFERRED">

<Variant WRITTENFORM="FMN-binding domain protein" type="orthographic"/> <Variant WRITTENFORM="FMN-binding domain-containing protein" type="orthographic"/> <Variant WRITTENFORM="unknown" type="orthographic"/> <Variant WRITTENFORM="FMN-binding" type="orthographic"/> <Variant WRITTENFORM="Pden_2486" type="orthographic"/> <Variant WRITTENFORM="nirI" type="orthographic"/> <SourceDC sourceName="BioThesaurus" sourceId="Q51699"/> <PosDC posName="POS" pos="N"/> <DC att="uniprot_ac" val="Q51699"/> <DC att="speciesNameNCBI" val="318586"/>

</Entry> </Cluster>
```

I need to import this content into postgresql. Kindly help me in this regard either direct procedure or convert XML to csv to PostgreSQL.

I need the tables with columns like

clsid, entryid, semType, baseForm, variant(writtenform), variant(type), dc(att), dc(val)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using Ruby with help of packages noko-giri and open-uri. As, my input file is so large in size. Many of the parser got failed and noko-giri helped in this.

I provided the answer with three columns, baseForm-variant(writtenform)-dc(val). This information may be a crisp information for the question.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("xai"))
ent = doc.xpath("//Entry")

value = String.new
ent.each do |e| 
    d = e.xpath("DC")   
    d.each do |f|       
        if f.attributes["att"].to_s =~ /uniprot_ac/
            value = f.attributes["val"].to_s
        end
    end
    f = e.xpath("Variant")  
    f.each do |g|
        puts "#{e.attributes["baseForm"].to_s}\t" + "#{g.attributes["WRITTENFORM"].to_s}\t" + "#{value}"
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, parse your xml file to obtain a file(s) that contain all of the info you need.

For example, if you want to have just one table with the attributes clsid, entryid, semType, baseForm, variant(writtenform), variant(type), dc(att), dc(val) then you just need one file that has these attributes (separated with some character). Each line in file would correspond to each row in table.

Next, you create table schema in Postgresql. Then use Postgresql's COPY command, which copies all of the data from file to table.

Note that if  your xml file is huge you should use event based parser. Something like SAX, StAX in Java for example.

**EDIT**
**NOTE**: libraries used: stax2-api-3.1.1.jar, woodstox-core-asl-4.1.1jar
Here is the code (hopefully it does what you need, if not I am sure it gets you started):

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package test;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2;
import org.codehaus.stax2.XMLStreamReader2;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    /*
     * dc(att), dc(val)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("CallToThreadDumpStack")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, XMLStreamException {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        Reader in = new InputStreamReader(fstream, "UTF-8");
        XMLInputFactory2 factory = (XMLInputFactory2) XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader2 parser = (XMLStreamReader2) factory.createXMLStreamReader(in);

        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("/home/aseke/Desktop/out.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outStream, "UTF-8"));


        boolean isCluster = false;
        ArrayList<String> dc = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> variants = new ArrayList<String>();

        /* You actually do not need all of these variables, it's just for clarity */
        String clsID = null;
        String semType = null;
        String varWritten = null;
        String varType = null;
        String entryID = null;
        String baseForm = null;
        String dcAtt = null;
        String dcVal = null;
        String s = null;
        while (true) {
            int event = parser.next();
            if (event == XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT) {
                parser.close();
                break;
            }

            if (event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
                String tag = parser.getLocalName();

                if (tag.equals("Cluster")) {
                    isCluster = true;
                    clsID = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
                    semType = parser.getAttributeValue(1);
                } else if (tag.equals("Entry") && isCluster) {
                    entryID = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
                    baseForm = parser.getAttributeValue(1);
                } else if (tag.equals("Variant") && isCluster) {

                    varWritten = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
                    varType = parser.getAttributeValue(1);

                    variants.add(varWritten + "~" + varType);
                } else if (tag.equals("DC") && isCluster) {
                    dcAtt = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
                    dcVal = parser.getAttributeValue(1);

                    dc.add(dcAtt + "~" + dcVal);
                }
            }

            if (event == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT && isCluster) {
                if (parser.getLocalName().equals("Cluster")) {
                    isCluster = false;
                    //clsid, entryid, semType, baseForm, variant(writtenform), variant(type), dc(att), dc(val)
                    // Use tabs as delimiter for Postgre COPY
                    String outStr = clsID + "/t" + entryID + "/t" + semType + "/t" + baseForm + "/t";

                    /* Add all variants */
                    for (String var : variants) {
                        String tmp[] = var.split("~");
                        varWritten = tmp[0];
                        varType = tmp[1];
                        outStr += varWritten + "/t" + varType + "/t";
                    }
                    /* Add al DCs */
                    for (String ss : dc) {
                        String[] tmp = ss.split("~");
                        dcAtt = tmp[0];
                        dcVal = tmp[1];
                        outStr += dcAtt + "/t" + dcVal + "/t";
                    }
                    // remove last tab "\t"
                    outStr = outStr.substring(0, outStr.length() - 2);
                    out.write(outStr);
                    variants.clear();
                    dc.clear();

                }
            }
        }

        // close all streams
        fstream.close();
        out.close();
        outStream.close();
    }
}
```

**I formatted you input xml**. So input file looks like this:

```
<Cluster clsId="UNIPR_NIRI_PARDP" semType="geneProt">
    <Entry entryId="UNIPR_NIRI_PARDP_1" baseForm="Protein nirI" type="PREFERRED">
        <Variant WRITTENFORM="FMN-binding domain protein" type="orthographic"/>
        <Variant WRITTENFORM="FMN-binding domain-containing protein" type="orthographic"/>
        <Variant WRITTENFORM="unknown" type="orthographic"/>
        <Variant WRITTENFORM="FMN-binding" type="orthographic"/>
        <Variant WRITTENFORM="Pden_2486" type="orthographic"/>
        <Variant WRITTENFORM="nirI" type="orthographic"/>
        <SourceDC sourceName="BioThesaurus" sourceId="Q51699"/>
        <PosDC posName="POS" pos="N"/>
        <DC att="uniprot_ac" val="Q51699"/>
        <DC att="speciesNameNCBI" val="318586"/>
    </Entry>
</Cluster>
```

**Output looks like this**. Note that it is delimited with tabs. Tabs will be later used as a delimiter in Postgre COPY command. You can change delimiter to any other.

```
UNIPR_NIRI_PARDP/tUNIPR_NIRI_PARDP_1/tgeneProt/tProtein nirI/tFMN-binding domain protein/torthographic/tFMN-binding domain-containing protein/torthographic/tunknown/torthographic/tFMN-binding/torthographic/tPden_2486/torthographic/tnirI/torthographic/tuniprot_ac/tQ51699/tspeciesNameNCBI/t318586
```

Comment: --"First, parse your xml file to obtain a file(s) that contain all of the info you need". Suggest me simple method to parse xml file into file which provide all my need.

Comment: @Palani Kannan If you are using java I suggest using woodstox implementation of StAX parser. It is very simple to use. I am sure you can find some examples online.

Comment: I am ruby user. I did using ruby. Thank you for help.